# "Column 'group_id' cannot be null". i cant register superuser?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

as i said i cant register superuser. this is not my project so I don't know it fully.
during the createsperuser, django requires a password and a phone number and that's it.

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    is_required = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Статус подтверждения'), default=False, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Статус персонала'), default=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey('Groups', verbose_name=_('Группа'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    center = models.ForeignKey('Centers', verbose_name=_('Центр'), on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    disease = models.ForeignKey('Disease', verbose_name=_('Заболевание'), on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    number = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Номер'), max_length=30, unique=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Электронный адрес'), max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Имя'), max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Фамилия'), max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    surname = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Отчество'), max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(verbose_name=_('День рождения'), null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_('Фотография Пользователья'), upload_to='users_photos/', blank=True,
                              default='media/site_photos/AccauntPreview.png')
    country = models.ForeignKey('Countries', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name=_('Страна'), null=True)
    city = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Город'), max_length=50, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Адрес'), max_length=100, unique=False, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('Дата создания'), auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True, )
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('Дата изменения'), auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True, )
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'number'

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number

    def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
        group = Groups.objects.get(id=self.group_id)
        group.number_of_people -= 1
        group.save(update_fields=['number_of_people'])

        super(User, self).delete()

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_staff

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return self.is_staff

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Пользователи'
        verbose_name = 'Пользователья'
        ordering = ['-created_at']


class Groups(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Название Группы'), max_length=100, null=True)
    number_of_people = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Количество людей'), default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Группы'
        verbose_name = 'Группу'
```

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, number, password, group_name, center_id, email=None, first_name=None, last_name=None,
                    is_patient=None, disease_id=None):
        user = self.model(number=number)

        user_group = Groups.objects.get(name=group_name)
        user_group.number_of_people += 1
        user_group.save(update_fields=['number_of_people'])
        user.group_id = user_group.id

        user.center_id = center_id

        user.country_id = Centers.objects.get(id=center_id).country_i

        user.set_password(password)

        if group_name == 'Пользователи':
            user.disease_id = disease_id
            user.is_patient = is_patient
            user.is_required = True
        else:
            user.email = email
            user.first_name = first_name
            user.last_name = last_name
            user.is_required = False

        user.save()
        return user

    def update_user(self, user, number=None, email=None, password=None, first_name=None, last_name=None, surname=None,
                    is_patient=None,
                    center_id=None, disease_id=None):
        updated_fields = ["updated_at"]
        if is_patient is not None:
            if is_patient:
                user_group = Groups.objects.get(name='Пациенты')
                last_user_group = Groups.objects.get(name='Пользователи')
                user.group_id = user_group.id
                user.is_patient = True
                updated_fields += "is_patient"
            else:
                user_group = Groups.objects.get(name='Пользователи')
                last_user_group = Groups.objects.get(name='Пациенты')
            user_group.number_of_people += 1
            user_group.save(update_fields=['number_of_people'])
            last_user_group.number_of_people -= 1
            last_user_group.save(update_fields=['number_of_people'])

        if center_id is not None:
            user.center_id = center_id
            user.country_id = Centers.objects.get(id=center_id).country_id
            updated_fields += 'center_id'

        if number is not None:
            user.number = number

        if email is not None:
            user.email = email

        if password is not None:
            user.set_password()

        user.save(update_fields=updated_fields)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, number,  password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('email', None)
        extra_fields.setdefault('first_name', None)
        extra_fields.setdefault('last_name', None)

        superuser = self.model(number=number, **extra_fields)

        superuser.is_staff = True
        superuser.is_required = False

        superuser.set_password(password)
        superuser.save()
        return superuser
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\fsd_medic\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 75, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\fsd_medic\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\fsd_medic\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\fsd_medic\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1048, "Column 'group_id' cannot be null")
```

I will be grateful for any of your help. I also want to add: for some reason, the previous developer moved the groups into a separate table, and because of this, such an error.
p.s it's 1 am and my head is already spinning, so sorry if the explanation is not very good!

Comment: This: `user.group_id = user_group.id` should be `user.group = user_group`

Comment: @DrummerMann, thanks, but doesnt work :((((

Answer (score 0):

In your User model, add a list called `REQUIRED_FIELDS` that contains `group`. That will make `manage.py createsuperuser` prompt for group value on superuser creation.